# INSERT result of SELECT to another query [OPENROWSET BULK]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big problem. I have tried to solve for 1.5 week, but nothing. I try to use OPENROWSET BULK
to get image file from parametrized path and put result to another query. Stored procedure looks:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateFoodProduct]
@Name NVARCHAR(255),
@ImagePath NVARCHAR(512),
@Description NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
@MainImage BIT = 0
AS
    DECLARE @Image VARBINARY(MAX);
    DECLARE @CommandImage NVARCHAR(1000) = N'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' +@ImagePath + ''', SINGLE_BLOB)Image';
    EXEC sp_executesql @CommandImage, N'@Image VARBINARY(MAX) OUTPUT', @Image = @Image OUT;
    PRINT @Image; --correct value
    SELECT @Image; --NULL (I don't know why)
    INSERT INTO FoodProducts (Name) VALUES (@Name)
    INSERT INTO FoodImageStore (Image, Description, FoodId, MainImage) 
        VALUES (@Image, @Description, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @MainImage)
```

Now, @CommandImage return specific value (correct), in next step I try to put @Image to FoodImageStore but in column **Image** I see NULL. I don't know why if

```
PRINT @Image; --return correct value
```

Please, try to explain me why is that and what I need to do to insert result of SELECT OPENROWSET BULK to another query.

Comment: **Warning** the above is dangerously open to injection attacks. Never blindly inject parameters into a dynamic statement. *Always* safely quote them or escape the characters within the parameter's value.

Comment: For example, someone could easily pass the value `C:\Test.csv', SINGLE_BLOB)Image; CREATE LOGIN SU WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER SU;--`

Comment: Ok, I undestand. I have to put received Image into database. So what is the best idea to do that?

Comment: @Larnu additionally I defined passed value and other people can not do that